# How do I make PythonTex accepts french accent?

Tags: french, pythontex

I have some strings to print using PythonTex.

With strings in english, no problem. E.g., I can use string like "a string of char printed using python" and it works

```
\pyc{print("a string of char printed using python")}
```

However, when I want to print french text with accents such as "une chaîne de caractères imprimée en utilisant python" it doesn't work at all!

```
\pyc{print("une chaîne de caractères imprimée en utilisant python")}
```

So, how I do that? This work :

```
\pyc{print(r"une cha\^ine de caract\`eres imprim\'ee en utilisant python")}
```

but is not very friendly!

Thanks you in advance if someone knows how to do and help me.

Here is a MWE to see the problem:

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, frenchb]{babel}

\begin{document}

  With english, no problem, I can use string 
like \verb|"a string of char printed using python"|:

  \pyc{print("a string of char printed using python")}

  However, I want to print french text with accents 
such as \verb|"une chaîne de caractères imprimée en utilisant python"| 
but this doesn't work and blocks like that raises an error:

   \pyc{print("une chaîne de caractères imprimée en utilisant python")}

How I do that?

This work :
   \pyc{print(r"une cha\^ine de caract\`eres imprim\'ee en utilisant python")}
but is not very friendly!

\end{document}
```

```
The error message is 
This is PythonTeX 0.15

----  Messages for py:default:default  ----
* PythonTeX notice
    1 message(s) could not be classified
    Interpreted as errors, based on the return code(s)
  Traceback (most recent call last):
* PythonTeX stderr - unknown on line 19:
    File "/py_default_default.py", line 67, in 


--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  essai - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am stupid! This is a python problem. Just need to use : \pyc{print(u"une chaîne de caractères imprimée en utilisant python")}  with the "u"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by the OP himself (see comment)